# Highcharts Stack column issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is the code link: https://jsfiddle.net/chong789456/a77pj67b/3/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
         categories: ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"],
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            var tooltip = '';
            tooltip = '<b style="color:' + this.point.series.color + ';">Type: </b>' + this.point.series.name + '<br>';
            tooltip += '<b style="color:' + this.point.series.color + ';">Clicks: </b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 0, '.', ',') + '<br>';
            return tooltip;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'           
        },
         series: {
            minPointLength: 10
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            color: '#8fdc87',
            name: 'orange',
            data: [
                14943,0,3857,34
            ]
        },{
            color: '#7CB5EC',
            name: 'apple',
            data: [
                0,0,0,0
            ]
        },
    ],
});
```

I have 4 categories(c1,c2,c3,c4) and 2 series(orange,apple).

The issue is, for category c4, the orange's number is 34 and the apple's number is 0, only apple showns in c4 as you can see in the chart. I want orange shows there and the tooltip should also show something like:
Type: Orange
Clicks: 34

I'm confused that Orange doesn't show in C4 as its clicks is not 0. Anybody can help? thanks tons!

=================================================

I have fixed this issue now! : ) Here is the link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/75zk3w08/1/

```
series: [
    {
        color: '#8fdc87',
        name: 'orange',
        data: [
            14943,null,3857,34
        ]
    },{
        color: '#7CB5EC',
        name: 'apple',
        data: [
            null,null,null,null
        ]
    },
],
```

The only different of these 2 examples is the series section. If i set the value to null, then it won't show in the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the yAxis: {min: 0, max: 100}
minimum and maximum of y axis.this will affect y-axis scale As in your example 
 you are only setting minimum y axis  please check the below

Comment: Hi Gourav, I have fixed this issue by setting the series value to null. But still thanks for your help : )